# JTable Plugin updateAction

Tags: jquery, swing, jtable

I am having a problem with the update action in JTable Plugin. Wondering if you please shed some light on it. Would appreciate very much. 
When I edit a record I get the Model and Model Year dropdowns. They are being successfully populated via AJax calls.  **The problem is when I save my Model and Model Year choices the record changes are not reflecting on the row that I am editing.** On the server side (struts Java) I am sending back the edited row based on what was picked in the dropdowns. The JSON response is in the exact format required, identical to what is expected during update action.

Is there anyway to make JTable replace the edited row with the values returned in the JSON object.  Here is my client side code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ModelMYContainer').jtable({
title : 'ModelMY Table',
actions : {
        listAction : 'itsModelMYTable.do?action=list',
        createAction : 'itsModelMYTable.do?action=create',
        updateAction : 'itsModelMYTable.do?action=edit',
        deleteAction : 'deleteAction'
    },
    fields : {
        model_create : {
            title : 'Model',
            options: 'getModelList.do',
            create: true,
            edit: true,
            list: false
        },
        modelyear_create: {
            title: 'Model Year',
            dependsOn: 'model_create', 
            options: function (data) {
            return 'getITSModelYearList.do?model=' + data.dependedValues.model_create;
        },
            create: true,
            edit: true,
            list: false
        },
        model : {
            title : 'Model',
            width : '10%',
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: true
        },
        modelyear : {
            title : 'Model Year',
            width : '10%',
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: true
        }
    }

});
$('#ModelMYContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the recordUpdated function to your script. Here is the example how to reload the jTable after update or insert:

```
recordAdded: function(event, data){
    $('#ModelMYContainer').jtable('load');
},
recordUpdated: function(event, data){
    $('#ModelMYContainer').jtable('load');
}
```

You can use the same function to update single row.

See more info here: http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Events#event-recordUpdated